# How to detect apostrophe in a char* argument?

Tags: c, string, program-entry-point, argv

I have a c file such that I pass arguments to as such:

```
./cfile [-size number]
```

e.g.

```
./cfile -size 22
```

Here is an example code for such a file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     if (argv[1] != "-size") {
          fprintf(stderr, "Wrong format");
          return 1;
     }
     // get_number is some function that returns int value of number if number, NULL otherwise
     if (get_number(argv[2]) == NULL) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Wrong format");
          return 1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

However, when I write

```
./cfile '-size' '22'
```

I cannot find a way of making C determine that the apostrophes should not be there.
I want to throw an error due to the apostrophes on each argument, but c seems to treat them as if they are not there.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: `argv[1] != "-size"` is _always_ true as those 2 pointers are always different.

Comment: The single quotes will be removed by your shell in any case; if you `printf("%s\n", argv[1])` it will not contain the single (or double) quotes.  This isn't under your program's control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are interpreted by the shell in order to separate the arguments.  They are removed before your program even sees them.

So your program will only see `-size` for `argv[1]`, not `'-size'`.

Also, when comparing strings, you need to use `strcmp`.  Using `!=` or `==` to compare strings is actually comparing pointer values which is not what you want.

Comment: I see, would there be any way for me to compile the program in my makefile that would prevent the shell doing this?

Comment: @Squarepeg What the shell does is completely independent of what any program it runs does.  The arguments are read and interpreted by the shell before your program even runs.